# React checkbox checked value won't visually update unless I reload

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

```
export const Cell = ({
  checkBox = false,
  checkBoxLeg,
}: {
  checkBox?: boolean;
  checkBoxLeg?: Bet | undefined;
}) => {
  const handleClick = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, leg: Bet | undefined) => {
    if (leg){
      leg.useInParlay = !leg.useInParlay;
    }
  };

  const { open } = useFantasyParlay();
  return (
    <div
      className='py-3 px-4 h-full flex flex-col justify-center cell-container'
    >
      <Text size="small">
        {children}
      </Text>
      {checkBox ? (
                  <input type="checkbox" checked={checkBoxLeg?.useInParlay} className="cell-checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleClick(e, checkBoxLeg)}/>
                ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have the above code for a cell with a checkbox.  My value is properly changing on the underlying `Bet` object however the input checkbox being visually checked or unchecked won't update unless I re-render the page.  Not sure what could be wrong, `checked={checkBoxLeg?.useInParlay}`

I have checked linked to the `Bet` property that is properly being updated.

Comment: You're breaking one of the fundamental rules of React state: Don't directly modify state objects. More: https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state

Comment: You're directly mutating a state object rather than replacing it. Use a state setter with a new object (.e.g, through spread syntax) to re-render.  See also this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709550/react-doesnt-rerender-component-when-props-change